# How to check whether the field exists in Firebase, if it exists then print its value, if it does not exist, then add it with an empty value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to make a function check if Firebase has a **first_name: John field**, and if there is no first_name field at all, then return **first_name: empty value**.

below is a variable that takes the name from the query

```
late String userName;

  Future getuserData(userName) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) => userName = value.data()?["first_name"]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your document contains the "first_name", trying to get it like this `value.data()?["first_name"]` will return it's value, otherwise it will not find it and return `null`, so you can simply set an alternative ( which is the empty value ) like this:

```
  Future getuserData(userName) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) => userName = (value.data()?["first_name"]) ?? "");
  }
```

now after the `getuserData()` is called, the `userName` will be either the value from your database if it exists, otherwise it will be the alternative `""` which is an empty value.